# Simple braking chopper using Zener/TVS diode

Tags: zener, motor-controller, tvs, braking

So I'm designing a motor controller, relatively low power (100-150W, 12-48V supply), and I'm thinking about adding a braking chopper. Not strictly needed in this design, but it would be a nice value-add and maybe provide some useful protection for the 60V bridge MOSFETs.

All the chopper circuits I've seen use something fancy like a comparator/opamp to drive the chopper, but I can't help but wonder if there's a simpler solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA2HHK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Forgive the improvised pulse-generator setup; SW2 triggers at 1us and SW3 at 2us. Ideal pulse generators go to 0V after the pulse is over; this way it ends up at Hi-Z so the spike can actually get pulled down by a chopper. I guess I could have run a DC sweep instead of a transient analysis, but eh. Also, don't take the component models too seriously.)

Zeners are slow(-ish, I'd bet they're still faster than my MCU could turn off the bridge) but a unidirectional TVS should be faster than even an opamp; I've run various simulations and it looks like this is a sound idea. The obvious question, then, is why I haven't seen this before: probably because it's a bad idea for some reason I haven't thought of yet.

So, is this a brilliant insight and example of my great engineering prowess, or evidence that I'm clearly not there yet?

Comment: With the FET and Zener approach the FET will be pulled into the linear region and will have high dissipation. (That's why they use a comparator with hysteresis, so the dissipation is in the resistor bank, not the FET.)  It might be OK, but you have to calculate the thermals.  With the chopper, you have to be sure that the source can sink current (or there's enough other stuff on the bus) so that the regen energy doesn't just pump the source up to the point where something breaks down.)  Both approaches could work, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: @JohnD I'm a bit confused there? If I'm trying to chop an 80V supply down to ~55V with a 51V zener and a FET with a 4.4V (say) threshold, the FET gets turned with a Vg of ~25V, which will drive it to saturation. For a capacitive load, at least, most energy will be dissipated in the resistor before the bus voltage enters the critical 51-55V range that would put the FET in linear mode.

Comment: Do you have an Energy, Power  loss budget?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about? I've only heard that term used in transmission line sorts of applications, which this is most definitely not.

Comment: Every part has resistance. Define the currents and power loss allocated to each part to meet your efficiency spec.  If you plan on dumping 150W, you need to figure out what the current and losses are in each part.  MOtors have DCR, Batteries have ESR, Switches have RdsOn, Caps have ESR  Compute the power loss and energy transfer based on your specs

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Not really? I mean, loss is bad, but my DC bus ultimately comes from the mains, not a battery or something like that. Thermal issues would become limiting, as would ampacity of the cable used to connect the DC-powered controller to a remote power supply, but it's not like I'll quibble over a few milliwatts. All that said, I'm still not sure exactly what you're getting at.

Comment: If motor surge is 10x rated and rated is 150W/48V=3A what caps will accept this ripple current.. Not feasible.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That circuit, as simulated, shows a peak loss through the zener of 8W for 2us, a peak loss through the FET of 8W for 50us, and a hearty ramp-down through R2 over 4ms, starting at  63W and ending at at 30W before the zener turns back off. (If that's what you're interested in.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94185/discussion-between-reid-rankin-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).